# Autocomplete in Xcode not showing all the classes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autocomplete, xcode7

I've got Xcode 7.2 on a MacBook Air.
I'll directly show you the problem

### My Problem:

in ViewController.swift:

```
let appdelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
```

This line is giving me an error: Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate'

---

In my AppDelegate.swift, the UIApplicationDelegate is named as "AppDelegate":

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{
```

Still why does it show me this error.

#### This is just an example in this view controller. this same problem occurs in one more class (or file), BUT not in all classes (or files)

### Solutions I've tried:

- restarting, reinstalling Xcode.
- rebooting my mac.
- Deleting 'DerivedData' folder which is located in /Library/Developers/Xcode/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete in XCode not working as expected (from using other IDE's)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717028/autocomplete-in-xcode-not-working-as-expected-from-using-other-ides)

Comment: The solution for the issue ain't working for me

Comment: You should try force casting it: `let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate`

Comment: if you cast it with as? you get back an optional, so you need do that:
`let appdelegate : AppDelegate? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate`

Comment: Not force casting not working. Getting the same error