# Xcode 7.3 class file searching is not available when we import any file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode7.3

Facing issue in Xcode 7.3 with autocomplete list of class files.

[image]

In Xcode 7.2 displays whole list of classes as we start typing.

like : `#import "Data"`

Xcode 7.3 class file searching is not available when we import any file

What should be the issue? Is it a bug?

Comment: I am using same xcode version 7.3 and it's fill auto complete works fine.

Comment: Try the solutions from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717028/autocomplete-in-xcode-not-working-as-expected-from-using-other-ides)

Comment: @NimitParekh Only class listing is not available. In Xcode 7.2 its working fine.

Comment: Sometimes it happen in any xcode becuase of memory issue. just restart xcode it will be fine and make sure that code completion is enable from xcode preferences.

Comment: @Lion I am facing this issue from many days. So I think restart of Xcode not an issue!

Comment: are you using beta version of xcode?

Comment: @Lion No. I never download beta versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the problem. Issue is all about the derived data folder. I have just deleted the derived data from the Mac.

Find derived data location from **Xcode > Preferences**

[image: Derived Data Location]

**/Users/__USERNAME__/Library/Developer/Xcode**

After that I restarted the Xcode! Bingo! It's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

select `Suggest completions while typing` in Xcode preferences

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure your target is compatible with Xcode 6.3.
>
> > Select your project target and go to project document and check
> >     project format

[image]

Comment: This is not the issue.